# Will BigQuery finish long running jobs with a destination table if my browser crashes / computer turns off?

Tags: google-bigquery

I frequently run BigQuery jobs in the web gui that take 30 minutes or more, saving the results into another table to view later.

Since I'm not waiting for the result to come soon, and not storing them in my computer's memory, it would be great if I could start a query and then turn off my computer, to come back the next day and look at the results in the destination table.

Will this work?

The same applies if my computer crashes, or browser runs out of memory, or anything else that causes me to lose my connection to Bigquery while the job is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is yes, the processing takes place in the cloud, not on your browser. As long as you set a destination table, the results will be saved there or if not, you can check the query history to see if there were any issues which caused it not to be produced.

If you don't set a destination table it will save to a temporary table which may not be available if you don't return in time.

I'm sure someone can give you a much more detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you have not defined destination table  - you still can access result of the query by checking Query History. You should locate your query in the list of presented queries and then expand respective item and locate value of Destination Table.
Note: this is not regular table  - rather so called anonymous table that is being available for about 24 hours after query was executed
So, knowing that table you can just use it in whatever way you want  - for example just simply query it as in below

```
SELECT * 
FROM `yourproject._1e65a8880ba6772f612fbe6ff0eee22c939f1a47.anon9139110fa21b95d8c8729cf0bb6e4bb6452946d4`
```

Note: anonymous table is being "saved" in a "system" dataset that is started with underscore so you will not be able to see it in UI. Also table name startes with 'anon' which I believe states for 'anonymous'